# Highcharts not being drawn in some cases when using data from MySQL (page elements created before database query complete?) PHP / MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I have a page which needs to fetch several different datasets from a MySQL database, and then use that data to define some jquery in such a way that graphs are drawn using that data (HighCharts to describe MySQL data).

Some users are reporting that the graphs are not loading, it is not a browser issue, nor is it consistent.

I've tried everything I can think of to debug the issue, and am left with the conclusion that the page is being loaded before the calls to the database are being completed in some cases, and so the graphs are not loaded.

As such I've resolved to put in a buffering page: the user selects which data they want to view, this is posted to a page with briefly "loads" (fetches all the data and stores it in $_SESSION), and then after a few seconds they are sent on to the page which draws the graphs, which now instead of drawing graphs based on database calls, is drawing them based on data stored in SESSION.

Is this a sensible way to proceed, or does this seem ridiculous to anyone more experienced?

Thank you

PS: My code is a few thousand lines long, and there's no one specific part which is not working (it works in 90% of cases), so I'm not sure how to usefully include code in this question.

Comment: I had to do a similar thing when using Highcharts for a sales dashboard, I ended up just storing all the data in a hidden table in the DOM and reading from that...dunno if that would suit your purpose...

Comment: Interesting, so you made your calls to your database, used it to create a hidden table in the DOM, then referenced that table to draw the charts? How did the relationship between the table and the charts work, is there something in the API to get Highcharts to read tables directly?

Comment: Yup....http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

Comment: Very interesting, I hadn't realised that, that's definitely worth a shot - want to write it up as a solution and I'll make it so? I reckon that's a better way around the issue than my buffering page.

Comment: You'll find its somewhat limited though, and depending on what youre doing, it may or may not serve your purpose....what data are you plotting?

Comment: A few different things, health and nutrition data, but it's all bar and column charts which are almost all Catagory / Number data points. I think it could work looking at the example you showed, what are the limitations you ran into?

Comment: The limitations I had was I was plotting a time series, so my table ended up being very very large....a few thousand lines...which took forever at points...but for what youre doing, I think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go...

```
 $('#container').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: document.getElementById('datatable')
    }....//other chart details....

<table id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Jane</th>
        <th>John</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Apples</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Pears</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Plums</th>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Bananas</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Oranges</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You can grab data from HTML tables, and use them in your charts...
Hopefully doing it that way will be better than storing it in Session variables..

Comment: another solution, might be to try doing a setTimeout on the chart load, and give it 3-5 seconds after document load....just another thought

Comment: Personally, Id try the setTimeout first, to avoid having to completely restructure your code....it might be that simple...lets hope.  Although, with such an 'inconsistent' error, it may be hard to tell if it works or not